# why Hbase with Hadoop map reduce performance is slow?

Tags: hadoop, cloud, hbase

I have configured hadoop1.0.3 on with 3 machines with fully distributed mode.on the first machine below jobs are running:

1)
`4316 SecondaryNameNode` `4006 NameNode`
`4159 DataNode`
`4619 TaskTracker`
`4425 JobTracker`

2)
`2794 TaskTracker`
`2672 DataNode`

3)
`3338 DataNode`
`3447 TaskTracker`

Now when i run simple map reduce job on it,it takes longer time to execute map reducejob.So i installed HBASE layer over Hadoop.now I have below processes for HBASE on 3 clusters.

```
1)    5115 HQuorumPeer     5198 HMaster    5408 HRegionServer
2)    3719 HRegionServer    3617 HQuorumPeer
3)    2937 HQuorumPeer    2719 HRegionServer
```

When i run map-reduce job on HBASE for 1,00,000 data it was taking 1 minute and the same for 1,00,00,000 data.now i want the result in just milliseconds. what steps should i  take for improvement?

I am a newbie so please help me out or suggest some layering over HBASE or hadoop so i can get result in just milliseconds.

I am summarizing below records:

```
hbase(main):007:0> describe 'weblog'
DESCRIPTION                                                                 ENABLED                                       
 'weblog', {NAME => 'info', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER =>    true
 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE'
 , MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS =>
 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', 
  ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
```

In weblog table -> info:category,info:hits are the columns.

`info:category  info:hits`

```
web             2

mail           10

ftp             1

web             3

mail           11

ftp             2
```

The data will be summarized in map reduce and stored in the another  table.

```
hbase(main):004:0> put 'weblog', 'row1', 'info:category', 'web'
0 row(s) in 0.0560 
hbase(main):004:0> put 'weblog', 'row1', 'info:hits', '2'
0 row(s) in 0.0560
```

please help on this.as i googled a lot but not be able to find anything that helps me.

Comment: I can not really figure out what you really want to do. Do you want to increase your hadoop speed ? Do you want to increase your HBASE data coherence ? Could you please give some clarification ?

Comment: i want just the data retireval speed in miliseconds .so i have applied HBASE layer over hadoop.

Comment: As launching a MapReduce job usually spends seconds, so it's hard to reduce the latency to milliseconds

Comment: that's right but if i can reduce it to <1 minute then also it will be fine using some tools like Impala,Phoenix..etc.but i don't know which solution will work for me or some performance related parameters that may work.so please help on this.

Comment: first it depends on your hardware configuration. For instance, your number of disks per node can highly increase your perfs. See https://www.cmg.org/measureit/issues/mit97/m_97_3.pdf and other links you may find on the net

Answer (score 5):

Hadoop, or any other batch processing system for that matter, is not a suitable choice if you have real time needs or if you need performance in ~ms. No matter how good your h/w is and how good your MR job is, there'll always be some initial delay when you run a MR job. And this is unavoidable. The reason being, when you submit a MR job, a lot of things happen before processing actually starts, like checking the input path, creation of splits, creation of map tasks etc etc.

It is correct that HBase provided real-time data access. But it doesn't hold good if you are accessing HBase through MR. If you really need ~ms access, you are better off writing normal Java+HBase API programs. But you won't be able to leverage the parallelism provided by MR then. So, you basically need to think well before you arrive at any decision.

Tools like Impala and Phoenix could be of help if you have real time needs. But they have their own + and -.

I would like to point one thing here. If your plan is to access **not-so-big** data at a time, you can definitely use HBase with sequential Java programs. But remember, random reads/writes always come with greater costs as compared to sequential acces. So, think well before you act.

Comment: Yes.the requirement is to access Big data coming in GBs in a day.so need to process this data and give the result in just miliseconds.

Comment: Please have a look at Impala in that case. MR is not gonna be of much help in such a scenario.

Comment: I guess Impala is by cloudera which may not be free version .Please suggest some open source technologies related to it.

Comment: Impala is from Cloudera and is open source. You can find more on impala here : http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products/cdh/impala.html

Comment: yes.but i am having apache based open source solution of hadoop so will it be compatible with impala.? and the second is will i be able to redistribute it?

Comment: With some tinkering it should be possible to use it with Apache Hadoop. And Impala is 100% open source (Apache License).

Comment: what about phoenix.? do you have any idea bout it?

Comment: Yeah. Phoenix is good. Based on HBase API. Uses co-procs and custom filters. But I don't don't know how much help you are gonna get. Last time when I had checked, there was no support for operations like joins, unions, intersections etc. Make sure it caters all that you need.

Comment: even not sure which to use impala or phoenix..? or else i need to test on both of them for performance criterias.

Comment: That would be better.